# How to read the data in csv and upload to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I have a file in csv which the format is like following:

```
"**Table1"
"*Field1","*Field2","*Field3","*Field4"
"Data1","Data2", "Data3", "Data4"

"**Table2"
"*Field1","*Field2","*Field3","*Field4"
"Data1","Data2", "Data3", "Data4"
```

I want the program can recognise the table 1/ 2 and upload the data to the mysql predefined table. I plan to use PHP. Has anyone tried to do this? I looking for an example and method! Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: MySQL actually supports loading data from csv directly, check : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11449458/145587

Comment: @OneOfOne - though it won't support this structure of data in the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library will probably make things a lot easier for you: https://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/.  I have used it in a recent project where I need to parse CSVs and insert into a MySQL database.

You can choose which table to insert into by using `$csv->getCell($x, $y)` where `$x` and `$y` point the cell with `"Table1"` or `"Table2"` inside.

So you could do:

```
$table_name = $csv->getCell($x, $y);
if( $table_name === "Table1" ) {
   // code to insert into table 1
} else if( $table_name === "Table2" ) {
   // code to insert into table 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that mean it able to search the table name e.g. Table1?

Comment: No worries.  Yeh, you need to put all the above in a loop.  Then you need to look at the cells with the table name inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$handle = fopen("./myfile.csv", "r");
if ($handle === FALSE) {
  exit();
}
// ignore header
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

// generate SQL query
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (col1, col2, ...) VALUES ";
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $sql .= '("'.$data[0].'", "'.$data[1].'", "'.$data[2].'", ...),';
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-1).';';
// then execute your query
```

**EDITED**

Comment: It seems it doesn't work. I copied some with the code as below:

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /home/ubuntu/parse_mysql on line 26
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /home/ubuntu/parse_mysql on line 26

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO `Table1` (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7, Field8) VALUES ";
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
  $sql .= '("'.$data[0].'", "'.$data[1].'", "'.$data[2].'", "'.$data[3].'", "'.$data[4].'", "'.$data[5].'", "'.$data[6].'", "'.$data[7].'"),';  <----- line 26
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-1).';';
// then execute your query
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();

Comment: @wingsuetcheung yes, sorry my mistake, I forgot to replace `"\t"` with `","` in the `while` statement, it should work now (code edited)