# Importing CSV data using PHP/MySQL- FULL EXAMPLE

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm following the first answer given here ([Importing CSV data using PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448307/importing-csv-data-using-php-mysql))
but I'm probably messing up some basic thing.

Here how my code looks now:

```
<?php

$accounts =  mysql_connect('localhost','root','mypass')
or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname",$accounts);

$fileName='./myfile.csv';

$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA INFILE '$myfile.csv'
     INTO TABLE tbname
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (ID,Entity,HOOK,Period,Status,Trade,etc)
eof;

$dbname->query($query);
?>
```

Im getting and error in my last line as it follows:

"Undefined variable: dbname in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode\loadcsv.php on line 17"

which prob mean that I didn't properly load that &dbname is as a db? I did managed to retrieve data from the same db using the same connection.

Any help in what the line

```
$dbname->query($query);
```

does is welcomed!

tks in advance!

Comment: If you work with `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`, you should also use `mysql_query` for your query.

Comment: @PKeidel. can you give a bit more insight? I tried:`$dbname->mysql_query($query);` and `$dbname->mysql_query($query, $account);` and didn't work! Any tips are welcomed!

Comment: I posted the correct code as an answer below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment before, you're mixing procedural and objective programming.
Functions like `mysql_connect`, `mysql_select_db` and `mysql_query` are procedural. So you have to go that way when you startet your project with this functions.

Your code should look someting like this:

```
<?php
$accounts =  mysql_connect('localhost','root','mypass') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname",$accounts);

$fileName='./myfile.csv';

$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA INFILE '$myfile.csv'
     INTO TABLE tbname
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (ID,Entity,HOOK,Period,Status,Trade,etc)
eof;

mysql_query($query); // <= HERE is the change
?>
```

You can't use `$dbname` because it is a variable that doesn't exists.

Comment: @PKeidel.Tks again but I'm having other issue bcs the change above did not work. I also tried to move the entire code to mysqli object oriented, but still stuck :-/(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436030/importing-csv-data-using-php-mysql-mysqli-syntax).

Comment: Not for this code. It runs fine its just that it does not upload anything in my tables.

Comment: Try `echo $query` and run the shown SQL statement via phpmyadmin or the console to check its functionality. Also add an `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your file.