# Separate one column into multiple columns

Tags: php, windows, xampp, eaccelerator

I have an excel sheet which I have a column of 3 mixed data separated by a column.

I want to separate that data by comma and insert into three different Fields in Mysql.

[image]

Comment: Look into https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel if it's truly an excel document and not a CSV file. Equally if it's one document, I'm sure you can do something manual.

Comment: please understand the question... in first column information is seperated by comma . i want to insert the data in separate field

Comment: Perhaps give the schema and a bit of code that you've tried that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create CSV file for this. So convert your XLS file in to CSV by Save AS & use below links will help

- http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql
- http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2013/05/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-mysql.html
- [Importing CSV data using PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448307/importing-csv-data-using-php-mysql)