# Automatically Import CSV into MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a website that is driven by a MYSQL DB. Everyday I download a CSV Report from an internal reporting system and upload it to the table. I can output and generate the CSV automatically from the system. My question is how can I have the CSV automatically consumed?  Can i Setup the CSV as an ODBC

No Previous Experience

Comment: look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/11449458/5193536

Comment: Use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` query to import a CSV into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a daily cron job on the machine that is running your website (or any machine that has access to your database).

This cron job has to get the CSV file from wherever it is created and import it to the database.