# Importing 70k+ rows to database from CSV with efficient memory and execution time

Tags: php, laravel

Can I get an idea; how can I import 70k+ rows to the database from CSV avoiding a lot of memory usage and time in Laravel (PHP)

Part of my code how I am trying to import:

```
                $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
                $reader->setInputEncoding('UTF-8');


                $spreadsheet = $reader->load($localpath);

                $spreadsheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
                $collection = LazyCollection::make($spreadsheet);

               if($key==null){
                  $key = array_map('trim', $collection->first());
                  $key_count=count($key);
               }

               $collection = $collection->except(0);

               foreach($collection as $row){
                if(count($row)==$key_count && !containsOnlyNull($row)){
                    $array[] = array_combine($key, $row);
                }
              }
```

Comment: Do you have any written code to do that ? Do you use an ORM to load your file ? as a general matter, avoiding memory usage is done by avoiding to store a lot of variables. Using an ORM will consume a lot of memory (depending on the ORM you use), the first step is by reading CSV iterating a file pointer instead of using a `file_get_content()` to get all the file in memory

Comment: Not Laravel specific, but still probably the best way to do it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448307/importing-csv-data-using-php-mysql

Comment: Hey, @SmasherHell I have added part of my code in question. can you please check!

Comment: @NigelRen I am doing field mapping and the structure of my CSV file varies. maybe it will not work in my case

Comment: @Pusku in your foreach you should do your business logic persisting data (line per line or every 100 lines), because as I see it, you're using a `LazyCollection` for nothing as you store the entire CSV in your `$array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to import this file with minimal usages of memory and time using LazyCollection. Here is the code sample how I did that:

```
    LazyCollection::make(function () use (&$csv_data,$key_count){
        $datas = $csv_data;
        foreach($datas as $line)
        {
            if(count($line)==$key_count && !containsOnlyNull($line)){
                yield $line;
            }
        }
    })
    ->chunk(1000)
    ->each(function ($lines) use (&$import_info, $user_id, $country, $csv_fields, $key, $total, $products,$allProducts, $sync_id,$import_id){
}):
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `laravel-excel` with chunk reading for that https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html

> To mitigate this increase in memory usage, you can use the
>   WithChunkReading concern. This will read the spreadsheet in chunks and
>   keep the memory usage under control.

This is an example of code you could write:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;

class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithChunkReading
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'name' => $row[0],
        ]);
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the link may help solving the problem, it is usual to put some code in your answer as links can at some point in the future become invalid.

Comment: hey, I do not want to use any packages. It would be great, If you can give me an overview of how the process should be to import a file fast and with minimal memory usage.

Comment: @NigelRen - agreed, should I remove the answer? this is the best I could come up with with the amount of information provided.

Comment: No need to remove it, but make it more a solution that could be implemented if needed.

Comment: @Pusku, you are use a package as well (PHPOffice), laravel-excel is just a laravel wrapper for this package

Comment: @NigelRen yes I am using one. I want to avoid this package too. btw thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome - if this helped you, please accept it so it can help others as well 

Comment: You can try `fastexcel` which is light and fast enough to import / export data. Hope it helps

Comment: Hope this can help, https://www.grok-interactive.com/blog/import-large-csv-into-mysql-with-php-part-1/