# Upload a csv file into mysql from the same server

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, upload

I have a csv files which are generated by other automated machines. These csv files are then transferred to a server  where my web application resides via ftp. I would like the user to upload these files into a mysql database residing on the same server or better still automate by any means the importation of these files into the mysql database.
I have no idea how

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448307/importing-csv-data-using-php-mysql help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing CSV data using PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448307/importing-csv-data-using-php-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

1. To store files  into a mysql server physical location
   a)pass the csv file to a stored procedure parameter
   SELECT @filename
   -> INTO OUTFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/QueryOutput.csv"

2)create a column of type longtext,blob or clob depending on the requirement
a)pass the file  location,
b)read the data into a variable
c) save it into a longtext column