# How can I check the whole file for any invalid ID format in a csv file before inserting csv file data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

How can I fix this code to check the ID column in the CSV file and print an error if there are any unmatched rows, or insert data to MySQL if there are no errors.

Currently my code echoes an error message only for unmatched data in the first row.

My code :

```
if(isset($_POST['Submitbtn'])){

    $uploaded_by = $_POST['uploaded_by'];
    
    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/tab-separated-values' , 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
    
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes)){

        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
        {
            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

            while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE)
            {
                $empno   = $line[0];
                $id   = $line[1];
                $code   =  $line[2];            
                $uploaded_by = $uploaded_by;
                

                if((preg_match("/^([0-9]{9}[x|X|v|V]|[0-9]{12})$/",$id))!=true)
                {
                    echo 'Wrong id number';
                    die;
                }
                else
                {       
                    $query = "INSERT INTO company (empno, id, code, uploaded_by) VALUES ('$empno', '$id', '$code', '$uploaded_by' ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    if($result)
                    {
                        echo 'Imported Successfully !';
                    }
                }
                    
            }                   

            fclose($csvFile);      
        }
        else
        {
           echo 'please try again.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Please upload a valid CSV file.';
    }
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: See also [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) too

Comment: `$uploaded_by = $uploaded_by;` doesn't look very useful.  Worth reading: [Importing CSV data using PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11449458/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

`die;` will stop your script entirely. So as soon as it finds a validation error with the ID it will end the whole program.

If you just want it to skip to the next row of the CSV then use [continue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) instead:

```
if((preg_match("/^([0-9]{9}[x|X|v|V]|[0-9]{12})$/",$id))!=true)
{
    echo 'Wrong id number';
    continue;
}
```

---

If you want it to check all the rows and ensure there are no validation errors in any of them before you start inserting data, then it requires a bit more of a re-design.

This is one possible approach:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submitbtn'])){

    $uploaded_by = $_POST['uploaded_by'];
    
    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/tab-separated-values' , 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
    
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes)){

        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
        {
            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
            
            $isValid = true;
            $lines = [];

            while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE)
            {
                $id = $line[1];

                if((preg_match("/^([0-9]{9}[x|X|v|V]|[0-9]{12})$/",$id)) != true)
                {
                    //mark is invalid
                    $isValid = false;
                    break; //stop the loop - once there's a single error we don't need to carry on
                }
                else
                { 
                    //add the data to the list of values to insert
                    $lines[] = [$line[0], $line[1], $line[2], $uploaded_by];
                }
            }

            fclose($csvFile);      
            
            if ($isValid === true)
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO company (empno, id, code, uploaded_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                
                foreach ($lines as $line)
                {
                    $stmt->execute($line);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Validation errors found. No rows inserted";
            }
        }
        else
        {
           echo 'please try again.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Please upload a valid CSV file.';
    }
}
```

---

N.B. If you are running a PHP version lower than 8.1, you'll need to use the following syntax for binding the query parameters:

```
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $line[0], $line[1], $line[2], $line[3]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: thank you ADyson for your reply. But actually I need check id format before  insert data to  MYSQL table. If found any unmatched id row in csv file stop process without inserting any data to data table.

Comment: @pawanishashi Do you mean that if even _one_ ID is wrong it should not insert _any_ of the rows?

Comment: @pawanishashi ok. It wasn't 100% clear from your original question. I have updated the answer with a solution for that.

Comment: Thank you very much ADyson. I tried your solution. But it shows the below error. ( Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\company\codes.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\company\codes.php(53): mysqli_stmt->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\company\codes.php on line 53 )

Comment: @pawanishashi what version of php are you using?

Comment: PHP version 8.0.20

Comment: Ah ok. You should really upgrade to a [supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). In the meantime, I've updated the answer with a version of the code you can use (the syntax I used, where the parameters are passed in via the execute() function, was introduced in PHP 8.1).

Comment: I tried your new coding lines. It works. But it inserts only the first row.

Comment: Ok. So have you done any debugging? There are probably 2 possible causes for that. Either `$lines` only contains one row of data (which would happen if the CSV only contains one row, or if errors occur while reading the data), or the SQL is crashing when trying to insert the second row. Do you have PHP and mysqli error reporting enabled? Have you done any basic checks on the content of $lines, or logged which pathway the code is taking etc? I tested my code on some sample data and it was working fine, so I'd suggest you need to debug yours in more detail in case something is different.

Answer (score 0):

well it is hard to say without an example of your csv content by the way i hope this can help you to solve your problem:

```
//this line tell your code to accept a lot of csv (and non csv) type
$csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/tab-separated-values' , 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');

//here instead you create a loop that tries to read the lines of the csv
while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE)

//but fgetcsv will return weird result if your csv content does not match some criteria
//as you can see in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php
//fgetcsv have some optional parameter:
fgetcsv(
  resource $stream,
  ?int $length = null,
  string $separator = ",",
  string $enclosure = "\"",
  string $escape = "\\"
): array|false
//so by default you need  to pass a comma separated csv
//any other type of csv could bring weird results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the whole file text with a single regex.

If the second value in any row does not qualify, halt the process.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/8OCmO5/1

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if (preg_match("/^[^,]*,(?!\d{9}(?:[xv]|\d{3}))[^,]+,/mi", $fileContents)) {
    // halt
}
```