# I am having a trouble for insert an csv file data to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I want to insert an csv file data to mysql database.The data is inserted but the values are in readable format.So please  help me to insert an original csv data to mysql databse.

These are my php content:

```
<?php 
include "config.php";
if($_FILES[csv][size]>0)
{
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];

    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,","))
    {
    $insert= mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts(contact_first,contact_last,contact_email) VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')");
    if($insert) {      header('Location: csv_upload.php?msg=success');  }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if (!empty($_REQUEST['msg'])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  Choose your file: <br />
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" size="1" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the result is:

```
Your file has been imported.

contact_id  firstname   lastname    email
1       
2   ÇcÌxLÚÞœHïÚÖûï]Å›*$A°>–›¸í…J%›•ŠôaËËACMÒÛÊˆ÷¼ÆJêŸ‰&Mœ;žÖ4BÎe— tˆYÛ>c~4$”‡–    
3   &Ú^Õü¼ÊÖÕ   
4   [A+Mû×áœ[­­XK¯52áÀ‹ËÃ`Þ%p‘„ôØÿ¨ð™ýà¡7Ô!?€ÚŠàû…&aQ}É6HH;8‚ÆÉÚ`Ò¤¬iÓÖI[-Û¬/¸ÓÍùž0¶–ì  þ>§±óæÌeçäâE;µ°ck;¶ÒÔàÙ“)
5   C“ì cc¾”?fñÑ}pô|6˜1%M0Á§*¡‡˜<€ä·ÍÒ­¿ÿÿPK!sÛª@<#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels¼”ÁJ1†ï‚ï°än²­Z¥4íTèÁ‹Öˆ›ÙÝØM²LR·}{§BÁ–.Z)KNÃÿÿ˜ÉŸÉlmëä0ï$ð”%àr¯+%{[<]Ý³$Då´ª½É6Ølzy1yZEº*Ó„„T¬Š±ò    
6   ¬   
7   Ü7à¨Sx´*R‰¥hT¾T%ˆašŽþÔ`Ó=Íd®%Ã¹¾fÉbÓóïÚ¾(L>_Ypñˆ…¨H kã–$ª°„(™U¦Ž~šyîí®ùì5ù>®# S5ÇïÎ Ø qd÷ 
8   úå–ÕòÌVf·Ð•Dìöõ]ÆË+V0õfH}¯Ì&Ï›Š²*°î×¸O²3·ùxG_²LpÉ×*]h…¾_ó8‡`šOs†è´{‚®gþC5ùùÅèQ^Ì=EV/´ ™¢9Êä{:ý+ÎwøŒ¿"0JÐŒ$Sì@´(@œ ‚lŒD]„Ëù9Ú“)Ø7áåtMö…úÎ_(ÛlÂ¦H€ÎÃ$[R™¡$©fÍx 
9   ½%’r…{„•    þDRóØ6“BË†:žsÁ]°0’Åê¦VÚÐÕýtF‹v8¼€—¼0ÚêÊ]ÑUÅö’å’
10   xl/workbook.xmlPK-!ûb¥m”§³
```

Answer (score 1):

`10   xl/workbook.xmlPK-!ûb¥m”§³`

That says you're uploading an XML workbook

You would first need to convert the file to a comma delimited CSV

Answer (score 0):

1. Have yout tried with another csv file? Maybe it's a formating error
2. Do you have to strictly do that trough php? Why not just run directly a sql query like this?
3. Read this:

   - [Save CSV files into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432511/save-csv-files-into-mysql-database/11432767)
   - [PHP script to import csv data into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876043/php-script-to-import-csv-data-into-mysql)