# Scrape CSV data to SQL table using PHP, LOAD DATA from URL with Javascript object, (beginner)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web-scraping, stock-data

(I'm learning and not a pro, so please excuse any faux pas)

I am aware that the PHP, LOAD DATA function may be what I need, but I can't get to the file behind the Java Object.

I am trying to update a SQL table, i.e. overwrite matching dates, with data from a CSV file from Javascript buttons on one of these websites:

-"Download Data" from https://www.investing.com/rates-bonds/us-10-yr-t-note-historical-data (adjusting dates would be ideal)

-"Download Range" from https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/Znh18/price-history/historical

-"Download Spreadsheet" from http://quotes.wsj.com/bond/BX/TMUBMUSD10Y/historical-prices

The data looks something like this

```
Time,Open,High,Low,"Last Price",Change,Volume,"Open Interest"
02/08/18,121.0781,121.25,120.5313,120.8906,-0.10939999999999,2938115,0
02/07/18,121.2031,121.6094,120.8594,121,-0.48439999999999,2201308,3569670
```

I have used the http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ utility to extract individual pieces of data, but that seems laborious if a file exists.

e.g. currently this is my code for finding table data on the WSJ page using the file_get_html() function:

```
...
// Finds the last cash price
foreach($html->find('span[id=price_quote_val]') as $e){
    echo str_replace("/32.","",str_replace(" ",".",$e->plaintext)). ' last cash price<br>'; 
    $field='Last';
    $value=str_replace("/32.","",str_replace(" ",".",$e->plaintext));
    include('table_update.php');
    }
....
```

Thanks!
Chris

I have read other posts, including:

[Save CSV files into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432511/save-csv-files-into-mysql-database/11432767)

[Importing CSV data using PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448307/importing-csv-data-using-php-mysql)

Comment: `fgetcsv` doesn't work?

Comment: AP, I will look at that, but how do I get through the Javascript after calling the URL?