# How to import csv (semicolon separated) to mysql via php?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I got the following code which actually works for a comma separated csv file. But due to the fact im located in Germany I need semicolon separated import. Can anyone tell me where I can change this in my code?

Thanks a lot!

```
if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){

    //validate whether uploaded file is a csv file
    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

            //open uploaded csv file with read only mode
            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

            //skip first line
            fgetcsv($csvFile);

            //parse data from csv file line by line
            while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
                    $connection->query("INSERT INTO adressen (name, email, status) VALUES ('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."')");

            }

            //close opened csv file
            fclose($csvFile);

            $qstring = '?status=succ';
        }else{
            $qstring = '?status=err';
        }
    }else{
        $qstring = '?status=invalid_file';
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save CSV files into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432511/save-csv-files-into-mysql-database)

Comment: Can you explain where exactly a problem occurs? What **exactly** does not work when you use a different CSV format?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a delimiter where you want to break on. 
Please look at the php documentation it is a old function with lots of help on it
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) which has separator options to load directly from the local filesystem into a table.

You will need to enable [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) when you connect to MySQL.